# POST data from modelform_factory generated form

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

What I'm trying to accomplish is to save the data to the relevant model. Very much looking to mimic the Django admin interface.

urls.py

```
url(r'^admin/add/(\w+)', views.admin_add_object, name='admin_add_object'),
```

view.py:

```
def admin_add_object(request, model):
if request.method == "POST":
    # The code I need to save the posted data
else:
    model_name = apps.get_model("product", model)
    ModelFormSet = modelform_factory(model_name, fields=("__all__"))
    return render(request, 'product/admin/add.html', {'formset': ModelFormSet})
```

add.html

Here I simply access `{{ formset }}` to get the relevant input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def admin_add_object(request, model):
    model_name = apps.get_model("product", model)
    ModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(model_name)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ModelFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # do something fancy. Redirect or so...
    else:
        ModelFormSet = modelform_factory(model_name, fields=("__all__"))
        return render(request, 'product/admin/add.html', {'formset': ModelFormSet})
```

Something like that. You can read more about this in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-model-formset-in-a-view